# Spring + JPA (Hibernate) on Glassfish --> ClassVisitor problem

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, spring-mvc, glassfish

I'm trying to write a simple web app with Spring 2.5 (core + MVC) and JPA (using Hibernate for the persistence mechanism).  Every time I deploy, I'm getting a "Class not found exception" that points to ClassVisitor.

This is a known version problem with the asm library.  In a stand-alone app, I can make sure that the proper asm version is first in the classpath, but when I deploy them to the server, I'm still getting problem.

Is there some way I can guarantee that the server uses the proper jar file?

I'm tearing my hair out over this, and I don't have the hair to lose. :)

Thanks for any help,

Ken Kousen
ken.kousen@kousenit.com

Answer (score 0):

You could put jar file into your Glassfish domain's "lib" folder.